# NotificationListenerService как проверить установлен ли звук на уведомление

Tags: android

```
public class NotifGetService extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
        public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

            sbn.getNotification().sound //всегда null 
        }
    }
}
```